# How is it possible to list custom post types by "category" like with simple posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy, "partners". I would like to categorize these items, so I created a custom post type with a taxonomy.

```
register_taxonomy("partners-category", array("partners"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Partners", "singular_label" => "Partner", "rewrite" => true, "slug" => 'partners-category'));
```

I would like to list these posts by categories for example: categoryname-category.php. I know it's working only with posts, so what's the best way?

Thank you very much and sorry, I'm newbie.

Comment: This is a confusing question. I am not sure what is being asked.

Comment: You can read the answer below that. I thought it's easy.

Comment: You start off by registering a new taxonomy and then ask about listing by _category_, which is a built-in taxonomy and different from the one you created.

Comment: Nevermind, r1987 understood my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an template file called taxonomy-{name}.php to show the posts assigned to a custom taxonomy. So in your case it should be taxonomy-partners-category.php . Category related archive pages work only with "Posts".

Info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy . Scroll down to Custom Taxonomies display.